# Strange Out of Memory exception in C# with List or Strings or ado.net?

Tags: string, list, memory-management, ado.net, system.reactive

I have a big doubt. The problem is Out of Memory Exception in my class. But it seems something strange here. I have class in a dll.

```
 public class MyClass : IDisposible
 {
     List<ClassA> a_classLists = new .....// new instance.
     List<ClassB> b_classLists = new .....// new instance.

     public string Method1(int IDValue)
     {
         // do here some web service call and get some XML data from it.
         // parse the xml.
         // Iterate through a for loop and add each node value to a_classLists
         // Usually contains 10 or 15 items

         Method2();  // from here calling another method
         FinalSaveToDB(); // finally save the data to DB
         return "";
     }

     private void Method2()
     {
         // do here some web service call and get some XML data from it.
         // Iterate through a forloop.
         // parse the xml. [large xml data. ie, image in binary format]
         // For each loop add image binary data and other xml to b_classLists
         // Usually it contains 50 or 60 such large lists.
     }

     private void FinalSaveToDB()
     {
         // using sqlbulkcopy, i am saving the data in the 2 lists to 2 different
         // tables in the DB.
         // Tab lock is mentioned in sqlbulk class.
         // Actually 2 sqlbulkcopy class for 2 lists.
         // Only 1 sql connection opens, then do the sqlbulkcopy. [there is no dataset or datareader]
         // sqlconnection closes. I am using "using" clause for sqlconnection, bulkcopy etc
         // these all are working fine.
     }

     private void Dispose()
     {
         // here nulling everything
         // proxy null
         // all the lists null....
     }
 }
```

This is the class I am instantiating 1000 times using reactive framework's Observable.Start
method as shown below...

```
  private IObservable<string> SendEmpDetails(Employee emp)
  {
    using (MyClass p = new MyClass())
    {
      return Observable.Start(() => p.Method1(emp.ID), Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    } 
   // here I hope it will call the Dispose and release all objects in the class.
  }

   // This EmployeeLists contains 1000 employee objects
   EmployeeLists.ToObservable().Select(x => SendEmpDetails(x).Select(y => new { emp = x, retval = y }))
                     .Merge(10)
                     .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
                     .Subscribe(x =>
                     {
                        SendStatus(x.retval.Item1, x.retval);
                     });
```

Even though, why i am getting out of memory exception ??? After starting the app, when it
process the 200th (or above) MyClass object, it throws error.

I forgot to mention 1 more thing, I am using VS 2010 and C# 4.0 (win7, 64 bit OS).

I need to log each activity. [ie, i need to understand the each and every process the app has gone through]. SO i declared a class [MyClass] level private string variable and assign each process details like "called this method", "got 5 records from this web service" etc.

```
    logdata = Environment.Newline() + "This method has completed";
```

So the error is thrown here saying out of memory with some evalution failed.

So I turned off the string evaluation check box from Options in VS.

Again, there is no use.

So I changed the string to StringBuilder and tried to append the activity string each time.

Still no use. I dont understand what is the problem in it.

Is this because all the threads are working parallel, do they exchange the MyClass resources ??? Why the objects are not released ???

Please help me in this matter.

Comment: Can you give the stack trace of the exception and what line of code it occurs on?

Comment: @Patashu Thanks. There is no stack trace error is showing. It is showing like - An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Inside exception window out of memery exception is like - Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. The error is thrown at the line where i am adding process activity to a string like - Logdata = WriteLogs("Exception Error @ : " + processname); // Logdata is the class level string variable in the MyClass.

Comment: @Patashu And this is the writelog method.                      private string WriteLogs(string newstring)
        {
            return Logdata + Environment.NewLine + newstring;
        }

Comment: After you make one of these strings for logging, is it kept referenced in memory? If you are making thousands or millions of different strings and they never go out of scope (are not being used by anything in memory and thus can be garbage collected) that may be what's causing you to run you to run out of memory.

Comment: @Patashu But this string is in the MyClass class and is set to null in the Dispose method. So each Logdata string variable is the part that single instance. right ? ie, if i create 1000 MyClass instance, then there will be only 1000 instance of logdata strings and whenever the process Method1 finishes, it is set to null thus i hope .Net is freeing the allocated memory. Just now i commented this line code where strings are adding and run the app. This time memory exception is thrown at sqlbulkcopy. I used 2 sqlbulkcopy object. 1 sqlbulkcopy object is used for saving first list objects...

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010, it comes with a memory profiler that you can attach to your program and use to determine what its heap is being taken up by, where it got allocated and what path of references to a live object is preventing it from being collected. This will help a lot :)

Comment: @Patashu the fist list contains 10 or 20 list object each list has a XML string in it. The second sqlbulkcopy is used for saving the objects in the 2nd lists which contains images in binary format. The error is ...-  using (SqlBulkCopy bcp1 = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null))
 {  bcp1.BatchSize = 10000; bcp1.DestinationTableName = "MyTable_B";
    bcp1.WriteToServer(reader1);  // error is here...error description is same as above i mentioned.
                        bcp1.Close();
                    }

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something obvious, but why nobody yet pointed out that "nulling" object in the dispose method serves absolutly nothing? You should close open connections, dispose objects that implements IDisposable etc...

Comment: and btw using (MyClass p = new MyClass())
    {
      return Observable.Start(() => p.Method1(emp.ID), Scheduler.ThreadPool);

you are disposing the object before the thread has a chance to even start
    }

Comment: More actual code needed. Too pseudo-codely for my diagnostic tastes.

Comment: @Dtex The likelihood is that this class does not need to used IDisposable at all, if OP is using 'using' for the sql bulk copy. Would be interesting to see the webservice call.

Comment: The issue here is that you are queuing 1000 workitems for the threadpool. A large number of large webservice calls (same number as threads in threadpool) and doing same amount of sql bulk copies. You will use a lot of memory! TPL or async/await or would be a better fit here